# MSSQL Sum total on dates from table 1 and table 2

Tags: sql-server, sum, subquery

I have this following problem:

I have two tables 1 table for customer bought items and the other for employee sales:

```
Table 1 (Emp)
EmpId 
ProductId
dateSold
Price
Qty

Table 2 (Cust)
CustomerId
ProductId
dateSold
Price
Qty
```

do this is the query im tring at the moment:

```
SELECT  SUM(EmployeeSales.productPrice * EmployeeSales.Qty + 
            userBoughtItems.ProductPrice * userBoughtItems.qty) AS Total, 
        EmployeeSales.dateSold, 
        userBoughtItems.dateSold AS Expr1
FROM    EmployeeSales 
INNER JOIN userBoughtItems ON EmployeeSales.dateSold = userBoughtItems.dateSold
GROUP BY EmployeeSales.dateSold, userBoughtItems.dateSold
```

I want to get the total of both tables on the same date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `join` repeats the right table for every matching row in the left table.  In your example I'd expect that to result in a lot of duplicated rows.  Consider using a `union` instead:

```
select  cast(dt as date)
,       sum(sales)
from    (
        select  dateSold as dt
        ,       productPrice * Qty as sales
        from    EmployeeSales
        union all
        select  dateSold
        ,       ProductPrice * qty
        from    userBoughtItems
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        cast(dt as date)
```

The subquery contains a list of all sales, and the outer query sums them per day.

If you're using SQL Sever 2005 or older, replace `cast(dt as date)` with `dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, dt))`.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'dbo.EmployeeSales.dateSold' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Sum(sales) is suppose to be Sum(SubQueryAlias) yes?

Comment: ok the sales i know what you mean now for the sum but what about dt?

Comment: The inner query should not have had a `sum` aggregate since the grouping happens in the outer query.  I've edited the answer.  The "SubQueryAlias" is just a name for the inner query.  The name is not used, but required by the SQL syntax.

Comment: another problem i think, first of all the query worked but, the problem its nit giving the correct answer since there is time in the datse aswell : 2012-05-07 <b>00:00:00.000 15</b>

Comment: OK, the answer is now modified to group by the day part of the date

Answer (score 1):

Without group by clause it could n't works  it throws the following error.

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Column 'employeesales.dateSold' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I changed slightly,

Use this

> select  dt ,       sum(sales) from    (
>           select  dateSold as dt
>           ,       sum(Price * Qty) as sales
>           from    employeesales group by dateSold 
>           union all
>           select  dateSold 
>           ,       sum(Price * qty) 
>           from    customerboughtitems group by dateSold 
>           ) as SubQueryAlias  group by
>           dt

Comment: this answer works aswell but i still need to compre with date only becuase in my date i have date time (2012-05-22  20:16:14.267) and i think this is messing up the query, im suppose to have 5 days only but 640 results are showing up...